# How to store Dynamic Id while using Selenium Commands?

Tags: selenium

I want to know the process how to store Dynamic Id in my test while using Selenium commands.

Problem:

I have actually on the page where the textarea I want to focus within a test. It has the id like this: `id="txt_00092"` and it's generated by db auto increment.

It's a comments textarea. Let's say in my test I add a comment over some post. So if I run this test again this becomes 00093. This is where I have a problem as to how to store this dynamic handling in my test.

I hope you understand where I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand fully your problem. Put down the problem with the ID for know and tell us what is the purpes of the test: Check if the text was fully submited? if so you can type and check if the last(or first, depend on your query oredeing, i.e Asc/DESC) div/td/whatever contains the text.

If you need to chek the ID it's a littel problem becuse here we need to breack the string and do that with JS it's tricky. Hope i help you.

Answer (score 0):

When the Xpaths are dynamically changing, using Xpath this way might work for you:

```
[starts-with(@id,'txt_0009')]
```